# Using ipfs add a second time fails

Tags: distributed-system, ipfs

I am following along with the [ipfs tutorial in the docs](https://flyingzumwalt.gitbooks.io/decentralized-web-primer/content/publishing-changes/lessons/create-webpage.html). I creating a simple web page. I executed the following commands

```
ipfs daemon
mkdir simple-webpage
cd simple-webpage
nano index.html
cd ..
ipfs add -r simple-webpage/
```

When using `nano index.html` I entered some basic HTML code. Then I used https://ipfs.io/ipfs/webpage-hash to visit the page. For the webpage-hash, I entered the hash the last command outputed for the directory. The link worked for me to visit the webpage. **However**, when trying this a second time with some different content I don't succeed and the outputed hash when running `ipfs add -r second-page/` does not work to visit the page.

Why does `ipfs add` fail when used a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to see the page from the node you added it to? That is, http://127.0.0.1:8080/ipfs/webpage-hash, if you're doing all of this on your local machine. If not, you might be handling the hash wrong. If you are, well, publishing to and resolving from the IPFS DHT are not a always-and-immediate thing, it seems… Maybe try [another gateway](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/)?

Comment: Yea it seems like the first one went through way quicker. Now I can finally see the second one as well! But good note on how to reach it through the localhost